# open a Pop Up view when saving data on Parse (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, popup

I'm making a register view on Swift for an app. I want to load a pop-up view when the user is successfully registered to add more data. I'm storing the data using Parse.

I'm using this code to save the data:

```
@IBAction func registerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if emailTextField.text == "" || usuerTextField.text == "" || password1TextField.text == "" || password2TextField.text == "" {

        createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Fill all data")

    } else {

        if password1TextField.text != password2TextField.text {

            createAlert(title: "Error", message: "Passwords must be the same")
        } else {

            activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
            activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
            view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents() // UIApplication.shared() is now UIApplication.shared

            let user = PFUser()

            user.username = usuerTextField.text
            user.email = emailTextField.text
            user.password = password1TextField.text

            let acl = PFACL()

            acl.getPublicWriteAccess = true

            user.acl = acl

            user.signUpInBackground(block: { (success, error) in

                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents() // UIApplication.shared() is now  UIApplication.shared

                if error != nil {

                    var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later."

                    let error = error as NSError?

                    if let errorMessage = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                        displayErrorMessage = errorMessage

                    }

                    self.createAlert(title: "Signup Error", message: displayErrorMessage)

                } else {


                }


            })
        }
    }
```

In the else statement, I wanted to add this code:

```
    let vc = (
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID")
        )!
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But it only works if I load it in after viewDidLoad and didReceiveMemoryWarning, ¿how can I load this Pop Up if there aren't mistakes saving the user data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine, you just forgot to add the implicit `self` declaration before some statements (the debugger should advise this to you in default). Try this:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID")
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```